# Arcgis javascript - Set different symbol for each graphic in feature layer

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I have a feature layer that contains 12 items with the same defined style. But I want to change each item to have a unique symbol when rendered.

```js
var Layer = new FeatureLayer("http://...my map server.../0");

Layer.graphics.forEach(function (entry) {
    // loop through each item
    console.log(entry);                        
    console.log(entry.attributes.FID);

    var symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({ "url":"/images/icons/fid_" + entry.attributes.FID + ".png", "height":20, "width":20 });  
    entry.setSymbol(symbol);
    var renderer = new esri.renderer.SimpleRenderer(symbol);  
    Layer.setRenderer(renderer); // <-- this appears to override all previous items
});

map.addLayer(Layer);
```

I omitted some code to keep this simple; what I have now sets a symbol, but it's the symbol of the last `entry` that is looped for all items.

I need each `entry` to have a unique symbol defined by its `FID` (0-11)

I've search through ArcGIS's JavaScript API docs and can't find anything that addresses this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the UniqueValueRenderer, which will allow you to symbolize features by attributes.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/uniquevaluerenderer-amd.html#uniquevaluerenderer